# Objective C Passing Data

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/g2kbc]

```
displaycontoller *show = [[displaycontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"displaycontroller" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Contacts *contacts = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

show.context = context;
show.contacts = contacts;
```

---

In the display view controller everything is ok,
and again I am passing the same data to the edit view controller

```
editcontoller *edit = [[editcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"editcontroller" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


edit.context = context;
edit.contacts = contacts;
```

---

In the edit view controller I get empty cells
If I print the data I get (null)

If I skip the detail view controller, from table to the edit view controller everything works great...
But when I do from table view to display to edit view, I get zeros(nill).

Comment: Give us a picture that we don't need a magnifying glass to read...

Comment: Please, use correct format in your post code and make a clear question

Comment: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/g2kbc

Answer (score 0):

In the display, insert these two logs before the two assignments and observe the log.

```
NSLog(@"context: %@", context);   // see any valid data
NSLog(@"contacts: %@", contacts);  // see any valid data

edit.context = context;
edit.contacts = contacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `edit.context = context` try

```
editcontoller *edit = [[editcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"editcontroller" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


edit.context = self.context;
edit.contacts = self.contacts;
```

Maybe there is some trouble with instance variables in your controller.

And log the variables there, to see, what's happening.